# A property about harmonic quadrilateral

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Point $A$ is the center of the circle. $BA\bot BE, FA\bot FE$. Prove $\displaystyle \frac{CG}{GD}=\frac{CE}{ED}$.

Comment: The answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054855/symmedian-and-bisectors-meet-at-the-diagonal/1441668 might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\triangle BGD$ is similar to $\triangle CGF$, 
$$CG:BG=CF:BD\tag{1}.$$
Similarly $\triangle BGC$ is similar to $\triangle DGF$, so
$$BG:DG=BC:DF\tag{2}.$$
From (1) and (2),
$$\frac{CG}{DG}=\frac{CG}{BG}\cdot\frac{BG}{DG}=\frac{CF}{BD}\cdot\frac{BC}{DF}=\frac{CF}{DF}\cdot\frac{BC}{BD}\tag{3}.$$
On the other hand, $\triangle BED$ is similar to $\triangle CEB$, so
$$BC:BD = CE:BE\tag{4},$$ 
and $\triangle CFE$ is similar to $\triangle FDE$, so
$$CF:DF = EF:DE\tag{5}.$$
From (3), (4), and (5), noting that $BE=EF$, we have
$$\frac{CG}{DG}=\frac{EF}{DE}\cdot\frac{CE}{BE}=\frac{CE}{DE}.$$